# Entity framework migrations to another database

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have created an asp.net application that used Entity Framework and migrations.
My migrations files created like following image.

[image]

But I need to migrate to oracle database. And how can I apply all changes or final state of database on oracle. Should I run migration commands in order? Or what is the best way.

Comment: Yes it has to in order

Comment: Unless you are doing something unusual, EF will do this automatically. It checks for migrations already applied and skips them if they exist or applies them if they don't in a single `update-database`.

Comment: Will I run only one command `update-database` ?